# Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null". org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5;

Tags: spring

Why the hell am getting this error , every says spring is easy but it is not . I have added beans.xml file in src folder only still spring is not able to find . I thought spring is easy

Can anyone say perfect answer to this